# Noise artifacts during Naudio stream

Tags: c#, .net, wav, naudio

I'm having some outputting my data as audio stream.

I've uploaded a [sound snipped](http://vocaroo.com/i/s1T3HqEfzeph) of a sine wave with the undesirable noise effect.

I think the issue is related that there is a small pause between data packages and somehow this produces this low, fairly regular **pop sound**

The AudioMonitor class gets its data via SetBuffer, each 250ms  aprrox. ~ 6000 samples.

1. Where does the noise originate from exactly ?
2. What can be done to fix this ?

**Edit** *Seems to be an issue that the data isn't seamlessly coming in. After one package was played, there is a pause, the waveprovider idling and the clicking noise occurs.

Isn't it possible to just get a silence for the time there is no sample ready?*

[Audacity view of the signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tGs8.jpg)

```
    using System;
    using NAudio.Wave;  // Version 1.7.0.13

    namespace aws
    {
        public class AudioMonitor
        {
            private BufferedWaveProvider waveProvider;
            private WaveOut wavePlayer;

            int audioFilter = 0;
            int sampleRate = 31250;
            int resolution = 8;

            private void CreateAudio()
            {
                if (wavePlayer != null)
                {
                    StopAudio();
                    wavePlayer.Dispose();
                    wavePlayer = null;
                    waveProvider = null;
                }

                waveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(new WaveFormat(sampleRate, resolution, 1));
                waveProvider.BufferLength = 31250;   // standard value: 31250

                wavePlayer = new WaveOut();
                wavePlayer.DesiredLatency = 300;    // standard value: 300
                wavePlayer.NumberOfBuffers = 2;     // standard value: 2
                wavePlayer.Init(waveProvider);
            }

            public bool StartAudio()
            {
                CreateAudio();
                if (wavePlayer != null)
                {
                    wavePlayer.Play();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

            public void StopAudio()
            {
                if (wavePlayer != null)
                {
                    wavePlayer.Stop();
                }
            }

            public PlaybackState GetPlaybackState()
            {
                if (wavePlayer != null)
                {
                    return wavePlayer.PlaybackState;
                }
                return PlaybackState.Stopped;
            }

            public void SetBuffer(byte[] b)
            {
                int indexWrite = 0, indexBuffer = 0, sizeBuffer;
                byte[] nbuffer = b;
                sizeBuffer = b.Length;


                // valid data

                for (indexWrite = indexBuffer; indexWrite < (indexBuffer + sizeBuffer); ++indexWrite)
                {
                    nbuffer[indexWrite] = (Byte)((nbuffer[indexWrite]) + 128);

                    if ((nbuffer[indexWrite] < (128 + audioFilter)) && (nbuffer[indexWrite] > (128 - audioFilter)))
                        nbuffer[indexWrite] = 128;

                }

                try
                {
                    waveProvider.AddSamples(nbuffer, indexBuffer, sizeBuffer);
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                }
            }

            public void SetBuffer(double[] d, double fac)
            {
                byte[] tmpBuf = new byte[d.Length];
                for(int i = 0; i < tmpBuf.Length; i++)
                {
                    tmpBuf[i] = (byte)(d[i] / fac);
                }
                SetBuffer(tmpBuf);
            }

            public void SetAudioFilter(int f)
            {
                audioFilter = f*3; // min 0 max 60
            }

            public void Finalize()
            {
                if (wavePlayer != null)
                {
                    wavePlayer.Stop();
                    wavePlayer.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: it may be because each packet does not end at a zero crossing. Putting very short fade-outs/fade-ins is one way to resolve this.

Comment: @MarkHeath      Thanks for your input. I tried a fadeout and it works according to a recording I made with Audacity, but the clicking noise seems to originate anywhere else.  http://imgur.com/3rQXRc0

Comment: There are two main causes of popping I'm aware of: the zero crossing issue already mentioned by @MarkHeath, and short lived clipping (i.e. sound wave has multiple samples at int.MaxValue or int.MinValue).  The first can be timing related (i.e. packets coming in out of order, etc.)  The latter is an error in recording or audio processing increasing the amplitude of the samples.

Comment: @MarkHeath http://i.imgur.com/ESn2QEG.png  This is how it looks like with fade-ins and -outs. Do you have any idea what the 2nd interruption could be, there should be a decline too, instead it goes to 0 in 1 x-step